# CSS only : size of image container same width with respective to screen size in rows

Tags: html, css

I have been working on 5 rows which has different number of images as shown in code and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkmjdok4/)

I have a problem making the width of image container same with respect to number images in each row, like in code first row has some 5 images , second row has 2 images , what i have been trying is the image container in second row should be same width as image container in first row

and the row of most images in it should occupy 100% width, i have tried a lot figuring the mistake. I don't want to use JavaScript

HTML code

```
<div class="con">
        <span style="display:table-cell;padding:11px;background-color:#D1D5D8;position:relative;">
             <span class="top-20-lable">a-block</span>
            <span style="display:block;text-align:right;margin-bottom:5px;">
                <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 1</span>
                <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 2</span>
            </span>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>


        </span>
    </div>


<div class="con">
    <span style="display: inline-block; padding: 11px; background-color: #D1D5D8; position: relative;">
        <span class="top-20-lable">b-block</span>
        <span style="display: block; text-align: right; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 1</span>
            <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 2</span>
        </span>
       <div class="imgHolder">
            <img src="" /></div>

        <div class="imgHolder">
            <img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder">
            <img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder">
            <img src="" /></div>
    </span>
</div>


    <div class="con">
        <span style="display:inline-block;padding:11px;background-color:#D1D5D8;position:relative;">
             <span class="top-20-lable">c-block</span>
            <span style="display:block;text-align:right;margin-bottom:5px;">
                <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 1</span>
                <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 2</span>
            </span>
         <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>

        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
            </span>
    </div>


    <div class="con">
        <span style="display:inline-block;padding:11px;background-color:#D1D5D8;position:relative;">
             <span class="top-20-lable">d-block</span>
            <span style="display:block;text-align:right;margin-bottom:5px;">
                <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 1</span>
                <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 2</span>
            </span>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
            </span>

    </div>


    <div class="con">
        <span style="display:inline-block;padding:11px;background-color:#D1D5D8;position:relative;">
             <span class="top-20-lable">d-block</span>
            <span style="display:block;text-align:right;margin-bottom:5px;">
                <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 1</span>
                <span class="top-add-tags">Tag 2</span>
            </span>     
         <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
        <div class="imgHolder"><img src="" /></div>
            </span>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.con {

    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:2px;
    display: table;


}

.imgHolder{
  border:6px solid #D1D5D8;
  border-top:3px;
  width:240px;
  height:9vw;
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:left;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color:#fff;

}
.imgHolder > img{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.top-20-lable {
position:absolute;
left:20px;
top:10px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.top-add-tags {
    background-color:#009DD9;
    color:#fff;
    padding:2px 5px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkmjdok4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap add the class `img-responsive` to the images:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="" />
```

If not, you can create a css class like the follow:

```
.image-responsive {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ....not for images , the question is about image containers, which should be same size in all rows in any resolution, and with above issues i am facing